# Nexus Repository is Empty

Tags: maven, nexus

I am running Nexus on my local machine, and I configured pom.xml and settings.xml as shown below:

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvkoD.png)
[settings.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZJQ4.png)

And when I enter the command mvn clean deploy, there is no error and nexus shows me the artifact when I browse:
[browse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cefZk.png)

But all of the repositories (including maven-releases) are still empty:

[repos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3D4t.png)

What am I doing wrong?

```
PS C:\Desktop\JavaCodes\SnakeGame> mvn clean deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.batuhanunal:SnakeGame:jar:1.0.9-RELEASE
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 19, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< com.batuhanunal:SnakeGame >----------------------
[INFO] Building batuhan 1.0.9-RELEASE
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ SnakeGame ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Desktop\JavaCodes\SnakeGame\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ SnakeGame ---
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ SnakeGame ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Desktop\JavaCodes\SnakeGame\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Desktop/JavaCodes/SnakeGame/src/main/java/Snake.java: C:\Desktop\JavaCodes\SnakeGame\src\main\java\Snake.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Desktop/JavaCodes/SnakeGame/src/main/java/Snake.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ SnakeGame ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Desktop\JavaCodes\SnakeGame\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SnakeGame ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0-M8:test (default-test) @ SnakeGame ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ SnakeGame ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Desktop\JavaCodes\SnakeGame\target\SnakeGame-1.0.9-RELEASE.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- install:3.1.0:install (default-install) @ SnakeGame ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Desktop\JavaCodes\SnakeGame\pom.xml to C:\Users\batuh\.m2\repository\com\batuhanunal\SnakeGame\1.0.9-RELEASE\SnakeGame-1.0.9-RELEASE.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\Desktop\JavaCodes\SnakeGame\target\SnakeGame-1.0.9-RELEASE.jar to C:\Users\batuh\.m2\repository\com\batuhanunal\SnakeGame\1.0.9-RELEASE\SnakeGame-1.0.9-RELEASE.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- deploy:3.0.0:deploy (default-deploy) @ SnakeGame ---
Uploading to nexus: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/batuhanunal/SnakeGame/1.0.9-RELEASE/SnakeGame-1.0.9-RELEASE.pom
Uploaded to nexus: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/batuhanunal/SnakeGame/1.0.9-RELEASE/SnakeGame-1.0.9-RELEASE.pom (1.6 kB at 7.7 kB/s)
Uploading to nexus: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/batuhanunal/SnakeGame/1.0.9-RELEASE/SnakeGame-1.0.9-RELEASE.jar
Uploaded to nexus: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/batuhanunal/SnakeGame/1.0.9-RELEASE/SnakeGame-1.0.9-RELEASE.jar (8.0 kB at 73 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/batuhanunal/SnakeGame/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from nexus: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/batuhanunal/SnakeGame/maven-metadata.xml (376 B at 12 kB/s)
Uploading to nexus: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/batuhanunal/SnakeGame/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded to nexus: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/batuhanunal/SnakeGame/maven-metadata.xml (394 B at 3.6 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.609 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-15T12:43:47+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please post the output of `mvn clean deploy` command.

Comment: I'am sorry for images, I couldn't figure out how to embed codes into page. Maven says "Build Successfull", I also can't upload artifacts to Nexus via UI. @seenukarthi